# Network request failed react native, works in postman

Tags: rest, react-native, ibm-watson

Hello I'm creating a react native mobile app, and I'm using a java backend that will communicate with IBM watson developer cloud.

For whatever reason I'm getting `network request failed` with no useful debug info, when I call the rest API hosted on 127.0.0.1:8080. I've looked around and it seems other people are having the same issue, but none of their fixes are working for me. My backend is currently working and I've tested it with postman with the following body using POST method at 127.0.0.1:8080/test/chat.

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"John",
    "message":"hello"
}
```

My code is as follows. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

**Backend.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, ActivityIndicator, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';

let myApiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
let path = "test/chat";


export const sendMessage = async () => fetch(`${myApiUrl}/${path}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        id: '1',
        name: 'john',
        message: 'hi',
        //context: 'null'
    })
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(response.Json.output.text);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

**Chatbot.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import { sendMessage } from '../components/Backend';


export default class Chatbot extends Component {


    state = {
        messages: [],
        text: '',
        context: '',
        output: '',
        message: 'book'
    };

    //onSend(messages = []) {
    //    this.setState(previousState => ({
    //        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    //    }))
    //}

    testSend() {

        sendMessage().then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Api call error");
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.testSend() }} style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    Send
                </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>           
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on Android, you need to use your computer's IP address instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Use your computer's ip address or change "myApiUrl" to '10.0.2.2' 
For more info visit android developer docs [emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)